# Is there a key command to open suggestion menu (see image) in ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

This has always bugged me and this morning I decided to try and find out if there is a key command to open the resharper suggestion menu and quickly up/down select the appropriate option. It's annoying to have to grab the mouse every time.

I checked the Resharper key commands list but couldn't spot anything that sounded like it would be it (although I found a few cool key commands I never knew about, particularly the encapsulate field command!)

Anyone know it if it exists?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This is unless you chose to keep the Visual Studio shortcuts instead of ReSharper ones.

Comment: Damn thanks! I've been using that key command for so long, but only thought it was for importing namespaces.